# gnome-software:failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so

Tags: gnome-software

When running Gnome Software via the terminal, I get the following error message:

> (gnome-software:6632): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin
>   /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so:
>   /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Gnome Software opens fine, just when loading the page for any software, it just get stuck in the loading part, and does not display anything!

I just also installed the `packagekit`, put the same error persist!

---

Just in case this is not fixable by just tweaking, and installing, I submitted a bug report:

- [Bug #1573453 “gnome-software cant find libgs_plugin_xdg_app_revi...” : Bugs : gnome-software package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573453)

Comment: For me, Gnome Software doesn't even launch.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I have the same exact problem on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, intermittently, and when launching from terminal I get the same exact error message. I do not know what packagekit is but `apt list | grep packagekit` on my machine returns a bunch of hits so I think I have it installed.

Comment: Also, may have found a clue. `file /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so` returns  `/usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: broken symbolic link to libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so.0.0.0`

Comment: Restarting causes the problem to go away.